# Is there any way to display a less than sign < in a popup using Infragistics UltraToolTipManager / UltraToolTipInfo?

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now.

I can't find a way to display a `<` *symbol* or `>` *symbol* in a popup using `Infragistics` `UltraToolTipManager` and `UltraToolTipinfo` without it breaking the ability to display formatted text such as **bold**. So if I include a `<` *symbol* the other `HTML` tags in the popup are not rendered because the `HTML` is broken due to an extra `<` *symbol*.

I have tried using `HTML` entities but that has made no difference.

Thanks for reading, here is my code:

```
    private void button3_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UltraToolTipInfo info = new UltraToolTipInfo();
        info.ToolTipTextStyle = ToolTipTextStyle.Formatted;

        String tooltipText = "x < y <br/><br/> <span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">This is bold.</span> And this is not bold.";

        tooltipText = tooltipText.Replace("<", "&lt;");
        tooltipText = tooltipText.Replace(">", "&gt;");

        info.ToolTipTextFormatted = tooltipText;

        ultraToolTipManager1.SetUltraToolTip((Control)sender, info);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace **only** those instances of `<` and `>` that you want displayed literally, not every instance:

```
 String tooltipText = "x &lt; y <br/><br/> <span style=\"font-weight:bold;\">This is bold.</span> And this is not bold.";
```

Comment: I feared it may be so. That's easier said than done. The tooltips are pulled from a database after previously having been entered by an operator. So I don't know in advance what the tooltip contains and examining the string to determine which < and > symbols are and are not part of an HTML tag is something I hoped not to have to do. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Likely not what you'll want to hear, but you may need to encode the input and cleanup the existing data.